# Me genera Error Código Vba - botón combinado y Botón de búsqueda

Tags: vba

Me genera Error el siguiente código Vba - botón combinado y Botón de búsqueda donde genera una nueva tabla con los datos de búsqueda

```
Private Sub btnbusqueda_Click()
    Dim ValorSeleccionado As String
    ValorSeleccionado = Me.cmbcampo.Value
    Dim txtbusqueda As String
    txtbusqueda = Me.txtbusqueda.Value
    Dim Filtro As String
    Filtro = ""
    If txtbusqueda <> "" Then
        Filtro = " WHERE " & ValorSeleccionado & " LIKE '" & txtbusqueda & "'"
        
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenTable "CCM_Contable_Colombia_SAP" & Filtro, acViewNormal, acEdit
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que error?

Comment: *Me genera Error el siguiente código* ¿Qué línea? ¿En qué momento exacto? ¿Has tratado de depurarla? ¿Qué tratas de hacer? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Supongo que tu error es en   *DoCmd.OpenTable "CCM_Contable_Colombia_SAP" & Filtro*. OpenTable abre una tabla, sin embargo le estas pasando como nombre de tabla parte de una sentencia SQL, en decir, quieres abrir la tabla "CCM_Contable Where....".  No daria error si el txtBusqueda este vacio ya que dejaria el nombre de la tabla como tal, pero si pones filtro, entonces, error.